# Does Express handle errors with status code values automatically?

Tags: express

**TL/DR** Does Express have some default error handling code that's not documented?

---

I'm encountering some puzzling behaviour with Express (v4.17.1) and it's default error handling.

I'm in the early stages of constructing an API. I put together a route handler and hooked it up with the first route, along with a number of unit tests.

My design is very similar to the one described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15317870/2008384): I have a custom class called `NotFoundError` which extends `Error` and includes a `statusCode` property.

The route looks like this:

```
router.get('/api/resource/:id', ...);
```

This error is passed to the Express `next` function when, for example, I query the database and can't find a row with the provided `:id` value.

Now, I was *expecting* to write an custom error handler which would handle a `NotFoundError` and respond with the 404 status code. But to my surprise, the test I wrote for the 404 error passed!

I played around a little with my code and found that changing the `statusCode` property on my custom error class (to `myStatusCode`) cause the request to fail with a 500 error (which was expected).

So Express seems to like the `statusCode` property and it seems to know what to do with it. I can't find anything in [the Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/) that describes this behaviour.

Is this undocumented behaviour? Or is something else going on?

Comment: How do you start your project ? With the seleton ?

Comment: @PimentoWeb No, from scratch. Added Express via `yarn add`; no other middleware in use at this point.

Comment: Yes express handle directly error, I cannot trace it precisely, but here is the piece of code where I stopped: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js#L134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is **Yes** - Express does "automagically" handle errors with a `statusCode` property. Thanks to @PimentoWeb for pointing me in the right direction.

It turns out that Express has a dependency called [finalhandler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/finalhandler) which returns the HTTP status based on the `status` or `statusCode` property of the error object:

> The res.statusCode is set from err.status (or err.statusCode). If this value is outside the 4xx or 5xx range, it will be set to 500.